# How to convert text to array using split

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to convert text to array using split **and** show the last line from the array in div ( which is named result) .my problem is How to use escape sequence in textarea that it detected as \n in javascript so it converted to array

```
 var txtBox = document.getElementById("textArea");
    var lines = txtBox.value.split("\n");
    // print out last line to page
    var blk = document.getElementById("result");
    blk.innerHTML = lines[lines.length - 1];

<textarea id="textArea" style="width: 710px;color: #ffffff;background: activecaption">
     On the other hand,<br/>
     we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of 
</textarea>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: the code  seems correct  ... you have error?  .. wrong  result?  no  result?

Comment: `<br />` tag cannot be included in the `<textarea>` tag. `'\n'` and `<br/>` are different

Comment: @scaisEdge no result

Comment: @DeepakKumar On the other hand,\n we denounce.... doesnt work too

Comment: @baao doesnt show last line of array

Answer (score 0):

looks like you missed your `trim()` method. So your last array was just "" (empty string). please review this one

```js
var txtBox = document.getElementById("textArea");
//you need to trim your string to avoid your array item contains "" null string
var lines = txtBox.value.trim().split("\n");
// print out last line to page
var blk = document.getElementById("result");
blk.innerHTML = lines[lines.length - 1];
console.log("Array length: " + lines.length);
```

```html
<textarea id="textArea" style="width: 710px;color: #ffffff;background: activecaption">
  On the other hand, <!--no need `<br\>` in text area-->
  we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of
</textarea>
<hr>
<div id="result">

</div>
```

Comment: why the last index of array is empty?how can i do that without trimI()?any changes in html?

Comment: `pleasure of'\n'
</textarea>` gives last index empty. Whereas `pleasure of</textarea>` will not cause this. Look at the '\n' before your `<textarea/>`

Comment: Thanks @DeepakKumar. Also I just edited my answer to remove `<br/>`. It was useless in textarea because it will be treated as string. `\n` will match on real enter (multiline). If you want to split value(`innerText`) inside `Div` for instance you can use `<br/>` to split,not with `\n`, but with `regex`. something like this `/<br\s*[\/]?>/gi`